# How to store the output of a table to a field in another table in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a requirement where I need to store the output of a temporary table to a field in another BigQuery table.

Lets say I have a temporary table:

```
Field1 Field2 Field3
USA    101010   Y
USA    101011   N
USA    110091   Y
```

BQ table

```
Field1  Field2  Field3
USA     BATCH1  USA|101010|Y
                USA|101011|N
                USA|110091|Y
```

Is it achievable in BigQuery?

I have tried with

```
insert into table (field_name) values (select concat(Field1,"|",Field2,"|",Field3) from temp_table)
```

I know that it won't work this way, so what do I need to do?

Comment: What is the schema type of the desired output table?  Specifically, you want a WHOLE table written to an output column?  How does the "temp table" come into existence?  Is it the result of some previous select?   Do you perhaps want a structured column type instead of a "string"?  Is it a repeated value given that there might be more rows in your temp table?

Comment: What's the underlying goal...putting a whole table into a field make give you just pain.

Comment: We have scenario, where I need to log the rejection records (which is a temporary BQ table - which used to refresh for each run) into a static log table which hold the file name, country, rejection content into a static BQ table. thats the requirement..